# Как скопировать блок сайта со стилями и скриптами

Tags: javascript, копирование, веб-сайт

Есть проблема. Нужно скопировать с сайта https://www.sentbe.com/ru/?source_country=KR блок вместе со стилями и анимацией (скриншот ниже)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал использовать SnappySnippet для этого, но он копирует только HTML и CSS. JS не сохраняется. Может, кто нибудь знает, как это сделать, а если не так, то есть ли какой нибудь другой способ, типа готового кода для создания такой же анимации?

Так в чем заключается сам вопрос.

Как мне скопировать блок сайта на свой компьютер, чтобы потом я мог интегрировать этот блок в другой сайт?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически никак. Тебе придется скопировать html блока, найти в css стили которые к нему применяются. Ну и наконец самое сложное это найти скрипт, который применяется к этому блоку.